# Installation of React has failed

Tags: reactjs, installation, npx

I am getting this error when trying to install React .

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Error
Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

```
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\React app
Done.
```

Also used following but not working

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

to install npm init react-app my-app

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to create a directory in `D:\React app`?  What if you create a directory without a space in the name?

Comment: I have created the directory manually and inside it ran the 
D:\React app>npx create-react-app my-app . Is that not the right way? This is my first project.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing things correctly.  What version of npx / npm are you using (check with `npm --version`)?  If you run a powershell and then `Get-Acl` on the command line from within the `D:\React app` directory what is your output?  Not sure what you're running into.

Comment: by the way new react doc no longer reccomend CRA https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

Comment: @VladVladov I just tried the npx create-next-app@latest but still giving error saying failed to install npm.

Comment: @stdunbar npm version is 9.8

Comment: maybe you need to run commands in wsl?